# Copy constructor not invoked (again)

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I don't like questions with debug sessions and memory pointers pasted, but I am forced to ask one like that. 
This is a question about invoking copy constructors. I know there are already answers about that, but I didn't find anything that would solve my problem

I have a Matrix class:

```
class Matrix {
    ...

    Matrix(const Matrix& other); // copy constructor, needed due to *data

    private:
    int *data;
};
```

Matrix contains a pointer to a static memory array `data`, so when I copy a Matrix, the static array should be also copied with `mempy`.

At one point, I want to copy Matrix object to another Matrix

```
debug("COPY BEGIN ");
debug("matricex before copy: " << &itsMatrix << " < " << &matrix);
itsMatrix = matrix;
debug("COPY END ");
debug("matricex after copy: " << &itsMatrix << " < " << &matrix);
```

The copy constructor should  be invoked to copy the `data`. Apparently, instead of invoking the constructor, only *values* of the pointers are copied; later when both memory matrices are deleted, *the same* pointer to `data` is deleted twice and I have seg fault

Here is a debug session:

```
1: Matrix.cpp MATRUX EMPTY 0xbf901a28 with empty data 0
2: include/SubArrayMax.hpp COPY BEGIN 
3: include/SubArrayMax.hpp matricex before copy: 0xbf901a28 < 0xbf901a3c
     --- here I should see a copy constructor ---
     --- but no debug string is printed ---
4: include/SubArrayMax.hpp COPY END 
5: include/SubArrayMax.hpp matricex after copy: 0xbf901a28 < 0xbf901a3c
6: Matrix.cpp DELETE MATRIX 0xbf901a28 with data 0x81d0550
7: Matrix.cpp DELETE MATRIX 0xbf901a3c with data 0x81d0550
 --- 0x81d0550 is deleted twice ---
```

and this is my copy constructor:

```
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& other) // copy construcutor
{
    ...
    data = new mval_t[dim.w * dim.h];
    memcpy(data, other.data, dim.w * dim.h * sizeof(mval_t));
    debug("MATRIX " << this << " after copying, data " << data);
}
```

I know that copy constructors can be reduced by compiler, I tried `-fno-elide-constructors` and I also had seg fault.

Any hint why this happens? or maybe there is a better way to deal with copying objects with side effects?

Comment: "Matrix contains a pointer to a static memory array" it's not static memory. `new` allocates **dynamic** memory.

Comment: It is worth studying the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Comment: @Rob: thanks, indeed this is what applies here. I had all but the `operator=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in your case the assignment operator will be called.

Just define

```
Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& other);

...

Matrix& Matrix::operator=(const Matrix& other) // overloaded assignment
{
    if (this != &other) // self-assignment is usually a problem, avoid it
    {
        ...
        // Stage 1: Do all dangerous stuff that can throw.
        int* tmp = new mval_t[dim.w * dim.h];
        memcpy(tmp, other.data, dim.w * dim.h * sizeof(mval_t)); 
        // In this case the copy is safe, but for memory allocation
        // can throw
        // If you need to allocate several things, perhaps it's better
        // to use std::nothrow and check the result, otherwise
        // throwing on the second allocation would leak the first one

        // Stage 2: Do a safe swap.
        //    Because there is no chance of an exception now we can mutate the object
        //    in an atomic way.
        std::swap(tmp, data)

        // Stage 3: Release any old resource.
        delete tmp;            
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Reverting my upvote because of the exception unsafe implementation.

Comment: @ybungalobill: well, the factual _implementation_ of the assignment operator has nothing to do with the OP's problem. Anyway, your vote is your choice. It would be more useful from your side to _provide_ a link to the exception-safe implementation.

Comment: Don't do it like that. Do all things that can throw (like memory allocation) to temporaries. Once you have established it will not throw then modify the object. Alternatively use the `Copy and Swap idiom`

Comment: @Loki: well, the OP's question is not about how to implement. Anyway, since it's already second comment on the topic, I've modified the code.

Answer (score 2):

The line in your sample snippet will not cause the copy constructor to be called. It will use operator = which probably wasn't implemented since the behavior you are getting matches the default shallow copy. 
Try implementing operator = with similar logic to your copy constructor. Don't forget to check for self assignment though.